# Help with CSS for IE6

Tags: css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-6, rounded-corners

My site looks bad in IE6, but fine in Firefox. It seems to affect the images and boxes I have made in css.

In Firefox it looks great, "Rounded Box" and no issues but in IE6 it comes out square and is not aligned!! Plus the forms I have also come out square and the background images are gone.

```
td.login_bar {
    border-radius:10px;
    border:solid 1px #666;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#efefef;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
}
.join_input {
    border:solid 1px #CCC;
    padding:5px;
    width:250px;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#999;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
}
.join_input:focus {
    border:solid 1px #666;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-image:url(../imgs/edit_small_ico.png);
    background-position:left;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-left:25px;
}
```

So what do I need to do to fix this issue? Or just ban IE6?
Do i need to format a new .css just for ie6+?

*UPDATE:
I updated my code thanks to you guys but it still looks bad, just not as bad lol so i will keep working at it thanks guys!

Comment: I vote for "just ban IE6".  Also note that `border-radius` no longer needs a vendor prefix. It works well without prefix in all major browsers. This doesn't solve your IE6 issue, but it does help for IE9 and Opera, which you currently do not support.

Comment: IE6 doesn't support border-radius. You'll have to use image hacks to do that.

Comment: Round corners aren't possible in IE6 using only CSS.

Comment: no longer needs a vendor prefix? i am new to that so i would change it how, i was designing the site for firefox only if i can only block ie users some how lol. but i will look into that more i might just have to make the site look ugly :( or look up "You'll have to use image hacks to do tha" - Microsoft killed my inner designer...

Comment: Is there a cross browser "rounded box" css i can change/update to?

Comment: Greg - http://caniuse.com/ provides a nice, quick reference for what browser (and version) supports what, as well as what browsers and CSS still need vendor prefixes. For the stuff that IE previous to 9 doesn't support (all CSS3, including CSS rounded corners), I recommend checking out CSS PIE. Also, make sure to add the standardized CSS (ie - `border-radius`) to your CSS.

Answer (score 2):

The border-radius properties are not supported in IE6. If you want those elements to have rounded edges you'll most likely have to put in a fallback for the older browsers using images.

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer didn't support `border-radius` until version 9 - I might recommend applying a behavior modification script like [IE-CSS3](http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/), though according to W3Counter IE6 use dropped to 2.86% for April which in my opinion implies that designers can finally start disregarding it altogether. As neat as some CSS3 abilities are, many features are still not in main-steam support. An alternative is to continue using images for your rounded corners until browsers catch up.

Comment: Thanks for the info and reply, i decided to go through it and adjust the css so it will look "OK' in ie6 + not the best but if they have ie6 they can think of it as a punishment haha.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue, after looking though 300 forums lol i found a hack that says it works in all browsers i tried it in ie6 and yep it shows my rounded boxes now!

```
td.login_bar {
    border-radius:10px;
    border:solid 1px #666;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#efefef;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
}
```

Is changed to:

```
td.login_bar {
    border-radius:10px;
    border:solid 1px #666;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#efefef;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -khtml-border-radius:10px;
    behavior:url(../border-radius.htc);
}
```

I put that file on the host and it works 100%, only thing is my form fields wont style but its ok if they come out normal it still looks good.

Answer (score 0):

You're using non-IE vendor-prefixed CSS extensions like -webkit-border-radius and so on. They're not going to work in IE6.

I would suggest downloading a virtual machine containing IE6 and doing some proper testing if you're dead set on supporting it properly. The way it handles CSS can be quite strange.

If necessary you can use conditional statements to include CSS for certain browsers, although it's far better to just try and make your CSS work across everything by default, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned, those -webkit and -moz and -o are mostly for bleeding edge browsers. But here is something I found quite useful myself for IE6. http://forabeautifulweb.com/blog/about/universal_internet_explorer_6_css/

Comment: Thanks for the link i will check it out

Answer (score 0):

**Even Microsoft** votes for "just ban IE6", after the Chinese Google Hacks that occurred in 2010:

> Microsoft is aware of public exploit code published, the impact on
>   customers to try using Internet
>   Explorer 6 and of limited, targeted
>   attacks using this vulnerability in
>   Internet Explorer 6. As a result of
>   reports which we an update to its
>   Security Advisory 979,352 Customers
>   alert and provide actionable guidance
>   and tools to help with protection
>   against use of the IE vulnerability.

Please, don't waste your time making adjustments to make your code fit in a browser that is not even encouraged to use by its manufacturer. Instead try to make your code to be compatible with **modern browsers**.

Source:
[Hubpages: Microsoft Recommends Upgrading IE6 & IE7 Users To Upgrade Their Browsers](http://hubpages.com/hub/Microsoft-Recommends-Upgrading-IE6-IE7-Users-To-Upgrade-Their-Browsers)

See also:

- [After Google hack, Microsoft asks users to abandon IE6, XP](http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2010/01/microsoft-wants-you-to-ditch-windows-xp-and-ie6-for-security.ars)
- [Assessing risk of IE 0day vulnerability](http://blogs.technet.com/b/srd/archive/2010/01/15/assessing-risk-of-ie-0day-vulnerability.aspx)